# FinalSource is pointing to Binding destination

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, binding

I'm loosing it, I thought I would 'quickly' do a UserControl, add a dependency property to it and tests something, but it turns out that 'quickly' is likely to cause me to jump out the window of my 3rd floor office. I have a break point on my binding (SL5) and the FinalSource attribute (from locals) is pointing to the destination property of my control(with TwoWay binding this can almost make sense but I'm not using TwoWay binding). To add insult to injury, if I bind my control's DataContext everything works fine, if I bind my Dependency Property it does not work... (Maybe this is happening because its my last day of work for the year...). I don't know if I want an answer, but probably should, can anyone please explain this FinalSource issue to me?

Comment: I found the problem but not an explanation. In my host page I have a class called Presenter in which I have the value I am trying to bind from, if I add a class called 'Presenter' to my control binding wants to use the class in my control as the source and not the class in my page, this does not make any sense to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a workaround, instead of setting the control's DataContext to an instance of my presenter class I set the control's LayoutRoot's DataContext to an instance of my presenter class then all works fine. Irritating and bizarre...